# What is a random oracle?

Tags: cryptography

Could someone please explain what Random Oracle is all about?

I am trying to get into the nitty gritty of cryptography when I just came across the term "Random Oracle". A loose understanding of the term tells me that its an ideal system that accepts many inputs and gives out a single output, continues to throw the same output every time the same input is fed. Just that, the very first time, the output is randomized. I am still not clear about the understanding of this term and googling it out hasn't helped. Could someone please explain what it is?

Understanding of Random Oracle in Cryptography

Comment: [Cryptography.SO](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/879/what-is-the-random-oracle-model-and-why-is-it-controversial/880#880) and [this](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2011/10/08/what-is-random-oracle-model-and-why-2/) might be helpful, also

Comment: This question is off-topic here, and should be asked on the Crypto stackoverflow site.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - My bad. Rookie mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Random Oracle based on https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Random_oracle

In cryptography, a random oracle is an oracle (a theoretical black box) that responds to every unique query with a (truly) random response chosen uniformly from its output domain. If a query is repeated it responds the same way every time that query is submitted.

Stated differently, a random oracle is a mathematical function chosen uniformly at random, that is, a function mapping each possible query to a (fixed) random response from its output domain.